# How to verify whether a given string is a valid module name in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

How to verify whether a given string is a valid module name in Node.js?

Examples:

- `lodash` => valid
- `node-assertthat` => valid
- `eventemitter2` => valid
- `$%$` => invalid

What are the rules for Node.js module names?

Comment: Module names are ultimately going to resolve to a filename that gets loaded from disk.  I'm not aware of any restrictions on the name other than what can be in a legal filename on whatever OS you are running on.

Comment: That's not entirely true, because e.g. file names can contain the space character, while module names may not (it is possible to name a file `foo bar.txt`, but you can't have a node module called `foo bar`). Or am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have a reference that says that a node module name can't have any legal filename character in it?  Where do you find that a module name can't have a space in it if the OS allows those in filenames (generally a bad thing to do though)?

Comment: Yes. When you try to run `npm init` and give a name with a space in it, it will fail with an `Invalid name` error.

Comment: PS: And this brought me to https://github.com/npm/normalize-package-data#rules-for-name-field, which - at least - is a hint that not every possible file name is allowed.

Comment: Your first issue is an npm command line issue, a common issue for command line utilities and certainly a practical one to consider (I would never use spaces in my module names).  In fact, I'd probably stick to alpha numeric plus maybe hyphen and underscore and nothing else beyond that.  It just seems there's no reason to try to rock the boat more than that.